# Jquery: Select everything after class combined with "each" function

Tags: jquery, each

I just simply want to select each element after the class ".last".

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="option"></div>
    <div class="option"></div>
    <div class="option"></div>
    <div class="last"></div>
    <div class="option"></div>
    <div class="option"><img src="a.jpg"/>
    <table>
       <td><tr>1</tr></td>
       <td><tr>2</tr></td>
    </table>

    <div class="option"></div>
</body>
```

Jquery:

```
$('.option').nextAll(".last").each(function (i) {

       $(this).css('background-color','red');

});
```

What I want to acomplish:

```
<body>
    <div class="option"></div>
    <div class="option"></div>
    <div class="option"></div>
    <div class="last"></div>
    <div class="option" style="background-color:red;"></div>
            <div class="option" style="background-color:red;"><img style="background-color:red;" src="a.jpg"/>
    <table style="background-color:red;"><td style="background-color:red;"><tr style="background-color:red;">abc</tr></td>
       <td style="background-color:red;"><tr style="background-color:red;">abc</tr></td>
    </table>
    </div>
    <div class="option" style="background-color:red;"></div>
</body>
```

EDIT:

I need to select ALL elements below .last class

Comment: Note that if all you are doing in the `each` is changing a CSS property, you don't need the `each` at all. The majority of jQuery methods apply to every element in the matched set by default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You almost had it:

```
$('.last').nextAll().each(function (i) {
```

or more succinctly:

```
$('.last').nextAll().css('background-color','red');
```

http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/

Answer (score 2):

Try this selector: http://api.jquery.com/next-siblings-selector/

You should be able to provide a selector for class="last" then a selector for anything after that:

```
$('.last ~ .option')
```

Answer (score 1):

Given what you want to accomplish, why do you need `each`?

```
$('.last').nextAll().css('background-color','red');
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/PWc3q/2/

```
$('.last').nextAll(".option").css('background-color', 'red');
```